# dynamically adding listbox at runtime

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I need to add listboxes to a windows forms application (C#) at application runtime. the issue I am having is I do not know how many boxes will be added... The application is going to check a specific path for dir's, and each dir currently listed needs to be a separate listbox... is there a way to do this? I currently am attacking it by creating 7 listboxes and making them visible or non visbile based on number of Dir's... but theres a chance of more than 7...

any help is much appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Something like `this.Controls.Add(new ListBox());`

Comment: Why don't you just make it work the way Windows Explorer does this?  Any user will understand having a TreeView of directories on the left, list on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Habib's answer, you'd create a dynamic ListBox, popuplate it, then add it to some container:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
// populate "lb" somehow
this.Controls.Add(lb);
```

The above code can be inside a loop.

You'd need to explicitly set a Location() for each ListBox, though, unless you added them to something like a FlowLayoutPanel which would arrange them automatically for you.  If you need better control of how they are arranged take a look at using the TableLayoutPanel.  You could dynamically change the number of rows/columns in it based on the number of directories you find.